# white patch on top of IOS Emulators

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing my first IOS app with Xamarin Forms & when I run it on IOS emulators, I see a White space below the status bar (on iphone 4) [image]on iphone 5s I see a white patch on top as well as a black patch on Top & bottom of the screen. [image]
What's the reason for this? How can we fix it?

Thanks

Comment: i think its related with the images resolution u should add default-568.png image to run it on iPhone5 chk your image resulution which you are using in background.

Comment: I added 2 images (sort of splash screens of the app) as mentioned here http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/
iPhone 4 Default@2x.png 640x960
iPhone 5 Default-568h@2x.png 640x1136

It did not work. I do get the full screen spash pages before app launches but the white patch remains on Top when the Login page is loaded.

Comment: Yo can set the View frame on the basis of screen size.

Comment: Hi @Divz this is my first iPhone app so sorry for not being thorough with all its intricacies. Could you point me to an example of how to do this? Thanks

Comment: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello,_iOS/hello,iOS_quickstart/
have a look of this

Answer (score 3):

That white patch on top was actually the Navigation Bar of the iphone. I understood this when accidentally using Title property in Xamarin Forms XAML page. 
Using below code has hidden it & made the app look full screen.

```
  //Hide Nav Bar 
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```